# Leaflet map scrolled when dragging the page on mobile

Tags: leaflet, mobile

I have a Leaflet map embedded in a div with vertical scroll. The scroll works well on desktop but on firefox mobile I get a strange behavior: when I scroll the page (touching outside the map) the map get scrolled as well.

When I finish the drag, the map goes back to its right position.

I couldn't manage to reproduce the error in a simple scenario so I made a gif:

[image: page scrolling affecting map]

Note that there is a marker (the image does not load but this is not relevant) that moves at a different speed than the background OSM layer.

All this happens even if I set the map options with dragging:false.

Does anybody know what can be affecting the map this way? Why it reacts at all to events that take place in the parent div?

UDPDATE: Added GestureHandler as suggested and the panel it installs gets also affected by the page scroll.

[image]

Comment: Not sure at this point. Also, please specify the versions of Leaflet and the web browser this is reproducible. As an interim solution, try adding https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling/ and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Firefox 59.0.2 on Android. Got a similar report from an Chrome on Android, no version specified. 

As I said, this is not easily reproducible. I already tried to embed a map in a scrollable div and it works well.

It can be reproduced on a test environment though: http://fergonco.org:8086/bench/1

checking gesturehandling now...

Comment: I found another hint. Selecting text on the page, like in pressing the word "Bewertung" for a while until it gets selected, makes the problem disappear: the page can be scrolled and the map does not get affected. Clearing the text selection makes the problem come back again.

Comment: Added GestureHandling to the map and their panel is also affected by the page scroll.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that this happens with Leaflet versions 1.2.0 and 1.3.1

Comment: And... we have a way to reproduce. It seems Leaflet gets confused when the div containing the map div has _overflow:auto_ and _position:fixed_ (and some scrolls appear, of course).

Just get the first example here (http://leafletjs.com/examples.html) and replace the div with this code:

`<div style="position: fixed; top:30%; bottom:30%; overflow: auto">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum ...
    </div>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum ...
    </div>
</div>`

Seems a bug: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6045

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug in the upstream software (see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6045 )